# Storing session variable after login in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I already implemented from scratch (not using Devise or any other gem) a simple login form. Just Sign In, not Sign Up.

My concern here is about setting a variable that will be used the entire session the user is logged in. I already know that session variable could be set like this `session[:user_id] = @user.id` in controller, but I would like to add a shop variable (for example, shop_number ) This need to be set by the user himself (with a another form perhaps) after user is logged in, before any other action.

What is the best practice to do so? I was planning to use multistep forms, not sure is the best idea in this situation.

Here it is my controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_nom(params[:session][:NOM])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos"
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
    end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/'
    end

end
```

And here it is my view:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

<h1>Login</h1>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.label :Usuario %>
    <%= f.text_field :NOM, placeholder: "Usuario", class: "form-control",  label: 'Usuario' %>
    <%= f.label :Contraseña %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Contraseña", class: "form-control",  label: 'Contraseña' %>
  </div>
  <p>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: If the user will be submitting a shop ID via a form, can you just do `session[:shop_id] = params[:shop_id]` in the appropriate controller?

Comment: Mmm... perhaps... Redirect to that form after login. And I think I should create methods like `require_shop` in the same way that I did with user `require_user` in the application controller

Comment: You can do that, also, why not add a shop input to the login?

Comment: Because you only get the shops that user can set after login.